# check for Existing TimeSlot for given date to avoid Conflicts in booking

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have Sharepoint Calendar List for booking Event now i want to check for Existing TimeSlot for given date to avoid Conflicts in booking.
For Example lets say i have booking on 7/27/2011 10:00 AM TO 7/27/2011 11:30 AM now if user try to book event on same day with anytime in Between 10:00 AM to 11:30 AM i want to reject it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an ItemAdding event receiver for the list.

I hope these will help.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672862/check-if-datetime-instance-falls-in-between-other-two-datetime-objects)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227927/getting-all-datetimes-between-two-datetime-in-c-sharp)