# How to get dates between two dates in C#

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I would like to get dates between two dates. Instead of expected **9** different dates, I get **875287** and *run out of memory*. What would be the problem with the code below?

`StartDate` value is `01/04/2016 00:00:00`

`EndDate` value is `10/04/2016 00:00:00`

```
var selectedDates = new List<DateTime?>();

for (var date = StartDate; date <= EndDate; date.Value.AddDays(1))
{
    selectedDates.Add(date);
}
```

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih Apologies, tired brain, didn't see how they were getting the infinite loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Getting all DateTimes between two 'DateTime's in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227927/getting-all-datetimes-between-two-datetimes-in-c-sharp)*

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You aren't assigning the value of `date.Value.AddDays(1)` to anything, so it ends up in an infinite loop. You'd need to change your code so that `date` is set to the result of `AddDays`.

```
for (var date = StartDate; date <= EndDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    selectedDates.Add(date);
}
```

Comment: This. Like `String`, manipulations on `DateTime` objects return a _new object_ instead of modifying the existing one.

Comment: Based on OP's explanation (which means this code compiles and works), this `date` looks like `DateTime?`, not `DateTime` because `DateTime` does not have a property called `Value`.

Comment: Your updated code does not compile either since `Nullable<DateTime>` does not have method called `AddDays`.

Answer (score 32):

*[LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)* solution (let's *generate* `selectedDates`):

```
  var selectedDates = Enumerable
    .Range(0, int.MaxValue)
    .Select(index => new DateTime?(StartDate.AddDays(index)))
    .TakeWhile(date => date <= EndDate)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it avoid incremental computation which is an anti-pattern. It's not even certain that the `AddDays(1)` idea is even correct.

Comment: Why does it need to create a new `DateTime?` ? What would be the issue with selecting the return value of `StartDate.AddDays(index)`?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: `StartDate.AddDays` has a return value of `DateTime`, but the asker had used a `List<DateTime?>` in his question. `new DateTime?` is simply a way of forcing the return value to the target type.

Comment: @Mou: If I understand you right, you're puzzled that I don't add any items. Well, instead of *adding* into *existing* list `var selectedDates = new List<DateTime?>(); for ... Add ...` I just *create* it: after executing *Linq* query `selectedDates` will appear to be a `List<DateTime?>` which contains the required dates

Answer (score 12):

As far as I can see, since [`AddDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays) method returns a new instance of a `DateTime`, it does *not* change the current instance since `DateTime` is [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Looks like your `date` is `DateTime?`, you can change this part as;

```
for (var date = StartDate; date <= EndDate; date = date.Value.AddDays(1))
{
    selectedDates.Add(date);
}
```

As usr pointed, this *might* be affected on DST. You might wanna check [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36789337/447156) as well.

Comment: Doesn't this have a bug due to the incremental nature of the computation?  If StartDate is at 2:30AM the time will shift if you ever hit a daylight savings day. AddDays does not behave like an integer.

Comment: @usr You are right, `DateTime` structure does _not_ consider DST in arithmetic operations. But based on OP's start and end dates, that shouldn't be a case. Updated my answer to point Dmitry's answer as well. Thank you.

Comment: Performance of this is horrible, as it expands the list many times over.

Answer (score 7):

A shorter notation using Linq's Range method uses the ability to already figure out the number of days using the `TimeSpan.Days` property after subtracting start from end.

Assuming the start is before end you'd end up with:

```
DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(1979, 10, 4);
DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(2016, 10, 4);

var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, (EndDate - StartDate).Days + 1)
    .Select(day => StartDate.AddDays(day))
```

If you need it to be Nullable, add:

```
    .Cast<DateTime?>()
```

If you need this to be a List, add:

```
    .ToList()
```

It's probably quite a bit more efficient than the other LINQ based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to change it up with a do/while

```
var selectedDates = new List<DateTime?>();
DateTime? StartDate = DateTime.Parse("01/04/2016 00:00:00");
DateTime? EndDate = DateTime.Parse("10/04/2016 00:00:00");

do
{
    selectedDates.Add(StartDate);
    StartDate = StartDate.Value.AddDays(1);
}while(StartDate < EndDate);
```